# Latching Switch Pinout

Tags: switches, datasheet, pinout, latching

I'm planning on incorporating a latching switch into my design:
https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Electrical-Switches_XKB-Enterprise-XKB8080-Z_C318860.html
 I also found the corresponding datasheet:
 https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1912111437_XKB-Enterprise-XKB8080-Z_C318860.pdf
 However, the pinout is really confusing to me and I honestly don't understand how to connect it properly:
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post pictures of the relevant parts of those documents into your question so we don't have to follow links to understand the question and so it will still make sense when the links die?

Comment: use an ohmmeter to determine functionality

Comment: The problem is, that I don't have the switch at hand. Instead, I have to order it first

Comment: that diagram is totally unclear ... perhaps you could contact the manufacturer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their website [http://www.helloxkb.com](http://www.helloxkb.com/index/product/index/catid/17.html?page=1) they have seemingly the same switch with different heights.

If so, the diagram of the [XKB8585-X-140](http://www.helloxkb.com/uploads/ajkg/XKB8585-X-140.pdf) and the [XKB8585-X-110](http://www.helloxkb.com/uploads/ajkg/XKB8585-X-110.pdf)

[image]

should equal the diagram of the [XKB8585-X-150] and the XKB8585 with bigger heights(http://www.helloxkb.com/uploads/ajkg/XKB8585-X-150.pdf)

[image]

Note the XKB5858-X-80 has drawn the solid and dashed lines differently.

[image]

If they are consistent in their drawing, based on the drawing above, on can **conclude for the XKB8080** that:

- pin 3 and pin 4 are common indeed.
- since the drawing XKB8080 has no dashed lines, no conclusion can be drawn which connection is made when released and which when pushed.

You could try their chat or pick one of the other key switched with slightly better documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Pins 1-2-3 form a SPDT switch, while pins 4-5-6 form a second SPDT switch. Together, controlled by the same manual actuator they produce a single DPDT switch.

The problem with this schematic other than the fact that it shows no broken contact and other than the fact it doesn't show any association between connections and switch position, is that every sensible interpretation of the horizontal arrow conflicts with the way the schematic for 123 and 456 are rotated with respect to each other.

The middle arrow indicates 2 and 5 are the common. But the schematic of 123 and 456 indicate that one of the outside pins is the common (and then it's not obvious which one actually is in that case, but I lean towards 1 and 6, but you could just as easily lean towards 3 and 4).

It's a crap diagram. When I first looked at the schematic I thought it was a SPST switch where 1-2-3 are the same node and 4-5-6 are the second node and both nodes get connected together by the switch. The only thing that make me look harder in the datasheet to see if it was "DPDT" appeared anywhere in the datasheet was the little right pointing arrow in the middle which seemed out of place with the aformentioned SPST interpretation.

Comment: So you pretty much have two switches in one, the pins 1, 2, 3 and 4, 5,6, where 1 connects to either 2 or 3 and 4 to either 5 or 6?

Comment: @NastyGamer Yeah. There should be a broken line representing a contact that flips between 2 and 3, and flips between 5 and 6 in that schematic.

Comment: But if pin 1 is the common for 2 and 3, isn't pin 6 the common for 4 and 5?

Comment: @NastyGamer Hold on. I just noticed that too.

Comment: @NastyGamer I corrected my post for the rotated schematic of the bottom switch. Yeah. The diagram is not clear which pin on both sides is connected at the same time or which switch position they connect at.

Comment: Might the assumption be correct, that 3 is the common for 1 and 2 and 4 is the common for 5 and 6 because these are the only pins, to which the other pins are connected?

Comment: @NastyGamer I can see how it can be interpreted it that way, but I think it's a very strange way to define it. But that's just my intuition talking.

Comment: @NastyGamer Actually if you take the center arrow at face value, what it says is that 2 and 5 are the common. in one position, 1 and 4 are connected, and in the other position 3 and 6 are connected. My biggest issue with this diagram is any sensible intepretation of that horizontal arrow conflicts with the way the schematic for 123 and 456 are rotated.

Comment: @NastyGamer Don't buy this switch.

Comment: You're probably right about that. Thank you anyways